# YouTube API 429 error while not using full quota

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Still a couple of weeks; we are getting more and more 429 HTTP Errors while making API requests to the YouTube API (mainly when trying to add or delete videos in a playlist). The error seems related to "quotas" indicated in the Google API console, but we checked this and are way below the limit according to the Google console report (we already have increased our quota value in the past, so this one should be more than enough).

Any idea why we are getting this error?

Error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 429,
    "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Resource has been exhausted (e.g. check quota).",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "rateLimitExceeded"
      }
    ],
    "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
  }
}
```

And our quota for the YouTube API:
[image]

Update: We are doing a "pause" of 2-4 seconds between each request addition in a playlist and still getting the error.

Comment: what is your current quota?  what is the exact error you are getting?  Pro tip console is lying to you its not accurate by any starch of the imagination.  Go by the error messages.   Can i see some code?

Comment: We got 100 000 000 on queries per day (we are using 4,97%) and 1 800 000 on queries per minute (we are using 1,99%) according to the Google console. I have added the error message.

Comment: can you check and make sure you only have one quote listen?   are you sure you don't still have the 10000 Per day quote alone with this extension quote?    can you post a screenshot?

Comment: https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas   <-- check here

Comment: No :/ see a screenshot here made on the Quotas admin page.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Do you have another idea? Thank you.

Comment: What happens when you click on the ? mark.

Comment: Nothing, just a tooltip on hover with "Quota usage per user is not displayed."

Comment: So; not sure what can I do here... Is there another place or how can I contact Google directly for this issue?